MongoDB ImportError with new pymongo release
After the new release of pymongo 4.9, I get this ImportError when using motor:
../***_mongo/src/***_mongo/async_context.py:4: in <module>
    from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient, AsyncIOMotorDatabase
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.6/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/motor/motor_asyncio.py:16: in <module>
    from . import core, motor_gridfs
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.6/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/motor/core.py:30: in <module>
    from pymongo.cursor import _QUERY_OPTIONS, Cursor, RawBatchCursor
E   ImportError: cannot import name '_QUERY_OPTIONS' from 'pymongo.cursor' (/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.6/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py)


Simply try running the code:
from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient, AsyncIOMotorDatabase


print(AsyncIOMotorClient)
print(AsyncIOMotorDatabase)

The current motor release is completely broken due to this.
I tried to use the latest release of motor (3.5.1)

For those experiencing this issue, please refer to the Jira ticket tracking it. We are currently investigating.
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-4771
Current fix is either:

Upgrade to motor 3.6.0 which is compatible with (and requires) PyMongo >=4.9: pip install --upgrade 'motor>=3.6'
If you're using motor <3.6 and can't upgrade, cap the pymongo version to <4.9: eg pip install --upgrade 'motor==3.5.1' 'pymongo<4.9'


Until motor gets updated to account for the breaking changes in pymongo 4.9, pin pymongo to 4.8.0

This worked for me (I only had mongoengine==0.27.0 prior to this)

I have this combination in my requirements.txt and it works.
motor==3.4.0
pymongo==4.8.0


If you are using mongoengine, you can fix it by imposing mongoengine==0.29.1 in the requirements.txt
